# How to get the first word of output from a PowerShell command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get first word from the output of this powershell command

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\Certificate::LocalMachine\My | findstr -i ecimas
```

Which is returning output like:

```
ffdrggjjhj     ecims.example.com
```

How can I return the string "ffdrggjjhj" only?

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed, as it looks like a common problem and no one has asked it before.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to split the output like so:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\Certificate::LocalMachine\My | findstr -i ecimas).split()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually powershell looks more like this.  Since there's objects, parsing isn't needed.

```
get-childitem Cert:\LocalMachine\TrustedPublisher | where subject -match wireless | 
  select -expand thumbprint

ABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCDEFABCD
```